# tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths with prototype cell

Tags: xcode, swift, tableview

I'm trying to insert one of the prototype cells in my tableView. I defined two prototype cells and gave them unique identifiers but I couldn't manage to insert them using a specific identifier.
There is no such function as tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths with identifier.

Any thoughts guys?

Comment: Why don't you use `cellForIndexPath:` method and get the right cell with your defined identifier and return it for the specific data model data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just got it done, my mistake was that I didn't know the cellForRowAtIndexPath will be called every time I insert or add a new cell.
I was trying to check for a condition on the shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier and insert a cell accordingly using a specific prototype. below is the code that worked out for me.

```
override func shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier(identifier: String, sender: AnyObject?) -> Bool { 
if identifier == "MainCatSelectedSegue" { 
   let TableRow = (tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row)! 
   let x = NSIndexPath(forItem: (Int(TableRow) + 1), inSection: 0)
   TableDataSource.insert(item, atIndex: Int(TableRow) + 1)
   tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([x], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)  
} 
return false 
} 

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell : UITableViewCell
    if TableDataSource[indexPath.row].Parent != "" {
        //This is a sub category
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("SubIncomeCat", forIndexPath: indexPath)        
    }else{
    cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MainIncomeCat", forIndexPath: indexPath)
    }
        let Item = TableDataSource[indexPath.row] as TreeItem
    cell.textLabel?.text = Item.Name    
    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use cellForRowAtIndexPath and inside the function, you can deque your prototype cell. here is an example

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        //you can also have if condition here to choose between ur prototype cells
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("unique id_1", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell 

        // Configure the cell...

        return cell
    }
```

Here is more common way to do this

```
//In parent class
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "MainCatSelectedSegue" {
        if let tvc = segue.destinationViewController as? YourTableViewControllerClass{
            tvc.model = self.model //the data you wanna populate the table view with. If the model is not from this current class, you can ingore this
        }
    }
}

//In tableview calss
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if indexPath.row % 2 != 0{
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("SubIncomeCat", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TableViewCell //or UITableViewCell if you have no custom calls for cells
    }
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(Storyboard.CellReusIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

    // Configure the cell...
    let rowContent = yourModel[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
    //now fill the cell with the content like...
    //cell.textLabel?.text = rowContent.text
    //cell.detailTextLabel?.text = rowContent.detail

    return cell
}
```

Comment: I tried using the dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier in my function but id doesn't work. After I insert the cell into the data source and the table view I can't apply the prototype to it. @Abhinav

Comment: override func shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier(identifier: String, sender: AnyObject?) -> Bool { 
if identifier == "MainCatSelectedSegue" { 
let TableRow = (tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row)! 
let x = NSIndexPath(forItem: (Int(TableRow) + 1), inSection: 0) tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([x], withRowAnimation: .Automatic) 
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("SubIncomeCat", forIndexPath: x)
 }
 return false 
}

Comment: select the code and click {} on top of the editors bar

Comment: The above code doesn't really accomplish anything. you dequeued the prototype cell but never used it. and its also not the right place to populate your table view

Comment: :( I'm not really clear then how this function works, would you please give me a hand.

Comment: ok, I'll edit my answer to a more general form on how to segue to a table view and display two custom prototype cells in it